# Priority queue using heap - difference between JavaScript and C++ implementation

Tags: javascript, c++, heap, priority-queue

I have rewritten in JavaScript the priority queue implementation with heap basing on similar implementation written in C++. I have completely no idea why C++ implementation works, whereas JS one don't. Can somebody eplain me the differences that cause the mistakes in JS implementation?

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int MAXINT = -2147483647;

 struct qelement
 {
   int prio, data;
 };

class queue
{
  private:
    qelement * T;  // kopiec dynamiczny
    int n;         // liczba elementów

  public:
    queue(int max_n);
    ~queue();
    bool empty();
    int  front();
    int  frontprio();
    void push(int prio, int v);
    void pop();
};

queue::queue(int max_n)
{
  T = new qelement[max_n];  // tworzymy tablicę dynamiczną
  n = 0;                    // kopiec jest pusty
}

queue::~queue()
{
  delete [] T;
}

bool queue::empty()
{
  return !n;
}

int queue::front()
{
  return n ? T[0].data : -MAXINT;
}

int queue::frontprio()
{
  return n ? T[0].prio : -MAXINT;
}

{
  int i,j;

  i = n++;
  j = (i - 1) / 2;

  while(i > 0 && T[j].prio < prio)
  {
    T[i] = T[j];
    i = j;
    j = (i - 1) / 2;
  }

  T[i].prio = prio;
  T[i].data = v;
}

void queue::pop()
{
  int i,j,v,p;

  if(n--)
  {
    p = T[n].prio;
    v = T[n].data;

    i = 0;
    j = 1;

    while(j < n)
    {
      if(j + 1 < n && T[j + 1].prio > T[j].prio) j++;
      if(p >= T[j].prio) break;
      T[i] = T[j];
      i = j;
      j = 2 * j + 1;
    }

    T[i].prio = p;
    T[i].data = v;
  }
}

int main()
{
  queue Q(10);   // kolejka 10-cio elementowa
  int i,p,v;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     v = rand() % 100;
     p = rand() %  10;
     cout << setw(2) << v << ":" << p << endl;
     Q.push(p,v);
  }

  cout << "----\n";

  while(!Q.empty())
  {
    cout << setw(2) << Q.front() << ":" << Q.frontprio() << endl;
    Q.pop();
  }
}
```

and here is incorrect JS code:

```
var MAXINT = -2147483647;

function qelement(data, prio) {
  this.prio = prio;
  this.data = data;
}

function queue(l) {
  var T = new Array(l);
  var n = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) T[i] = new qelement(null, 0);

  this.empty = function() {
    return !n;
  }

  this.writeq = function() {
    var i = 0;

    console.log('This is the whole heap');
    while(i < l) {
      console.log(T[i].data + ' : ' + T[i].prio);
      i++;
    }
  }

  this.front = function() {
    return n ? T[0].data : -MAXINT;
  }

  this.frontPrio = function() {
    return n ? T[0].prio : -MAXINT;
  }

  this.push = function(prio, v) {
    var i, j;

    i = n++;
    j = parseInt((i - 1) / 2);

    while (i > 0 && T[j].prio < prio) {
      T[i].prio = T[j].prio;
      T[i].data = T[j].data;
      i = j;
      j = parseInt((i - 1) / 2);
    }

    T[i].prio = prio;
    T[i].data = v;

  }

  this.pop = function() {
    var i, j, v, p;

    if (n--) {
      p = T[n].prio;
      v = T[n].data;

      i = 0;
      j = 1;

      while (j < n) {
        if (j + 1 < n && T[j + 1].prio > T[j].prio) j++;
        if (p >= T[j].prio) break;
        T[i] = T[j];
        i = j;
        j = 2 * j + 1;
      }


      T[i].prio = p;
      T[i].data = v;
    }
  }
}

var test = new queue(10);
var i, p, v;


for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  v = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  p = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
  console.log(v + ' : ' + p);
  test.push(p, v);
}

console.log('-------');

test.writeq();

console.log('-------');

while(!test.empty()) {
  console.log(test.front() + ' : ' + test.frontPrio());
  test.pop();
}
```

For example for input values (pairs "value : priority"):

```
32 : 6
88 : 3
40 : 1
99 : 8
70 : 8
24 : 7
4 : 6
3 : 9
40 : 1
30 : 5
```

The queue looks as follows:

```
JS:             C++:
3 : 9           3 : 9
99 : 8          99 : 8
24 : 7          70 : 8
70 : 8          24 : 7
32 : 6          32 : 6
40 : 1          4 : 6  
4 : 6           30 : 5 
88 : 3          88 : 3
40 : 1          40 : 1
30 : 5          40 : 1
```

Comment: How do you write code without knowing what it does?

Comment: @DeiDei If everyone would know what his code does then neither bug report exists.:)

Comment: What is it that "doesn't work" exactly? What happens when you test it? Are there any errors? What are the expected values and the actual values for both implementations when testing with the same input?

Comment: The expected behavior is that you debug your own code. When you run across a *specific issue* that you don't understand, you post a question asking about that issue. Dumping a couple hundred lines on us and saying, "why doesn't this work" isn't likely to elicit useful answers.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Glancing at the code you still have one place with `T[i] = T[j]` in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to replace

```
T[i] = T[j];
```

with

```
T[i].prio = T[j].prio;
T[i].data = T[j].data;
```

in `while` loop inside `pop()` method.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the push and pop methods. I rewrote them and the priority queue works correctly:

```
var MAXINT = -2147483647;

function qelement(data, prio) {
    this.prio = prio;
    this.data = data;
}

function queue(l) {
    var T = new Array(l);
    var n = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) T[i] = new qelement(null, 0);

    this.empty = function () {
        return !n;
    }

    this.writeq = function () {
        var i = 0;

        console.log('This is the whole heap');
        while (i < l) {
            console.log(T[i].data + ' : ' + T[i].prio);
            i++;
        }
    }

    this.front = function () {
        return n ? T[0].data : -MAXINT;
    }

    this.frontPrio = function () {
        return n ? T[0].prio : -MAXINT;
    }

    this.push = (prio, v) => {
        var i, j;

        i = n++;

        T[i].prio = prio;
        T[i].data = v;

        T.sort((qEl1, qEl2) => {
            if(qEl1.prio < qEl2.prio) return 1;
            else return 0;
        });
    }

    this.pop = () => {
        var i, j, v, p;

        if (n--) {
            T[0].prio = 0;
            T[0].data = null;

            T.sort((qEl1, qEl2) => {
                if(qEl1.prio < qEl2.prio) return 1;
                else return 0;
            });
        }
    }
}

var test = new queue(10);
var i, p, v;


for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    v = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
    p = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log(v + ' : ' + p);
    test.push(p, v);
}

console.log('-------');

test.writeq();

console.log('-------');

while (!test.empty()) {
    console.log(test.front() + ' : ' + test.frontPrio());
    test.pop();
}
```

Comment: Sorting the array with each push and pop certainly works, but it's terribly inefficient. There is a much better way. You might want to study up on binary heaps. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Binary%20Heaps/heaps.html

Comment: Infact it was just meant to be a proof of concept: altough it's not the most efficient way to accomplish the task, it showed that the problem lay in those couple of methods